# Trying to display complete table of Mysql database using JSP

Tags: jsp

I have a database with name "**jeet**".
The DB "**jeet**" has table "**jeet**".
I am trying to display complete table in tabular form.
Till now what I tried is-

```
<%@page import = "javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }catch(Exception e){}

    try{

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jeet","root","jeet");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from jeet");

        while(rs.next()){%>

            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%
                            rs.getInt("id");
                        %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%
                            rs.getString("bname");
                        %>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <%
                            rs.getString("author");
                        %>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <%
                            rs.getInt("price");
                        %>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

        <%}


    }catch(Exception e){

    }

%>

</body>
</html>
```

while I run this code on tomcat, I get the **http Status 404** .
and description for that is **The requested resource is not available.**.

What is the solution to get it done?

Comment: You have an application issue outside of this page: Look into your base configuration for using this jsp (what engine, framework, etc), because this code is not going to get you an answer on a HTTP 404 Page not found

Answer (score 0):

First of all replace this code:`<% rs.getInt("id");%>` 
to this `<%=rs.getInt("id");%>`. And do this for the others fields like this one.